# Terraform - local provisioner prompt for input - bash script

Tags: bash, automation, terraform, terraform0.12+

I am trying to use a bash script as a local provisioner for terraform.  Specifically the bouncer project to cycle instances in an autoscaling group.  The script works as expected outside of terraform but part of the script is prompting for input and terraform when it runs the script does not prompt but selects the first array option and moves on which is defeating the purpose for me.

Terraform portion:

```
resource "null_resource" "server_bouncer_vault_cluster" {
   triggers {
     trigger = "${module.vault_cluster.launch_config_name}"
   }

   provisioner "local-exec" {
     command = "../../../bouncerw canary -a '${module.vault_cluster.asg_name}:${var.vault_cluster_size}'"
   }
 }
```

script:

```
PROFILES=($(cat ~/.aws/config | grep '\[profile' | sed -n 's/\[profile \(.*\).*\]/\1/p' | sort))

echo "Which account are you trying to rebuild? Mayhaps one of these?"
for i in "${!PROFILES[@]}"; do
  printf "%s\t%s\n" "$i" "${PROFILES[$i]}"
done
read -p "Please select the number of the profile you wish to rebuild: " profilenumber
printf '%s\n' "${PROFILES[$profilenumber]} is your selection"

. awsume ${PROFILES[$profilenumber]} && ./bouncer "$@"
```

I have a bout 4 profiles and it always selects option `0` in the array when Terraform runs it rather than asking the user for input.

Thanks

edit: here is the terraform output with some info redacted:

```
null_resource.server_bouncer_consul_cluster: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
null_resource.server_bouncer_consul_cluster (local-exec): Executing: ["/bin/sh" "-c" "../../../bouncerw canary -a 'consul-us-east-1-staging20191023203410784500000005:5'"]
null_resource.server_bouncer_consul_cluster (local-exec): Bouncer already installed, using local copy
null_resource.server_bouncer_consul_cluster (local-exec): Which account are you trying to rebuild? Mayhaps one of these?
null_resource.server_bouncer_consul_cluster (local-exec): 0 production
null_resource.server_bouncer_consul_cluster (local-exec): 1 staging
null_resource.server_bouncer_consul_cluster (local-exec): 2 SFTP
null_resource.server_bouncer_consul_cluster (local-exec): 3 datascience
null_resource.server_bouncer_consul_cluster (local-exec): 4 master
null_resource.server_bouncer_consul_cluster (local-exec): production is your selection
```

Comment: Terraform doesn't have any mechanism for a provisioner to be interactive, because `terraform apply` itself is non-interactive once the plan is approved. I think to do this you'd need to make the script take the account as a command line argument, if it can't already, and then insert that argument into the command line based on a Terraform input variable.

Comment: We are using workspaces e.g.  `terraform apply -e prod` or `terraform apply -e stage` Do you know a way to extract the terraform workspace?  I can sort and assign an account based on that information

Comment: Can you try `read -p ... < /dev/tty` ?